# Targeting capital cities only in Tilemill/CartoCSS

Tags: data, tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

At a specific zoom level in my Tilemill map, I want to **only** show capital cities, and hide all other cities.

What data set could I use which will provide me with information oh whether a city is a capital city or not, so that I can hide/show based on that attribute?

Comment: You could argue that the Tilemill and Mapbox tags aren't necessary since your question is really about the datasets only

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Natural Earth populated places file](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/), you can filter on `[ADM0CAP=1]` to style only cities that are capitals of countries.